# Akka authenticateOAuth2Async: credentials missing

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, akka

I have the following:

```
  def myUserPassAuthenticator(credentials: Credentials): Future[Option[String]] = {
    log.info(credentials.toString)
    credentials match {
      case p@Credentials.Provided(id) if p.verify("a") =>
        log.info("Login success!")
        Future.successful(Some(id))
      case _ =>
        log.info("Login failure!")
        Future.successful(None)
    }
  }

  val authRoute = path("login") {
    authenticateOAuth2Async(realm = "secure site", myUserPassAuthenticator) { userName =>
      complete(s"The user is '$userName'")
    }
  }
```

when navigating to that endpoint and entering credentials, the log line

log.info(credentials.toString)

just becomes `Missing`. What is wrong here?

The content-type of the request is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`
and the data is `"grant_type=password&username=INSERT_USERNAME_HERE&password=INSERT_PWD_HERE"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap your route in `Route.seal` directive:

```
  val authRoute =
    Route.seal {
      path("login") {
        authenticateOAuth2Async(realm = "secure site", myUserPassAuthenticator) { userName =>
          complete(s"The user is '$userName'")
        }
      }
    }
```

from [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/authenticateOAuth2Async.html) it seems to rely on default rejection 401 if authentication fails

> Given a function returning Some[T] upon successful authentication and
>   None otherwise, respectively applies the inner route or rejects the
>   request with a AuthenticationFailedRejection rejection, which by
>   default is mapped to an 401 Unauthorized response.

and the [Route.seal](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html) provides exactly that:

> A Route can be "sealed" using Route.seal, which relies on the in-scope
>   RejectionHandler and ExceptionHandler instances to convert rejections
>   and exceptions into appropriate HTTP responses for the client.

Comment: Sealing it didn't help in my case, but maybe the request is wrong? I have updated my question.

Comment: I think the issue here is with your request headers. Akka Oauth2 implementation(OAuth2BearerToken.scala) expect to have the `Bearer` header set on the request ex: Authorization:Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Strange that it is simply "None" and no other error returned. Oh well.